# Python client for the OpenShift API and doing oc login

Tags: python, openshift

I have installed this python API:

https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python

and am trying to understand how to use that for basic operations that I would normally do on command line using the open shift client, e.g.:

```
oc login [my-openshift-instance]
oc project [my-project]
```

But I can't seem to find these basic operations in the above API. Is that API designed for some other purpose or have I simply missed those calls?

I tried:

```
from openshift import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
oapi = client.OapiApi()
project_list = oapi.list_project()
for project in project_list.items:
    print (project.metadata.name)
```

but it will not let me specify my open shift instance and user/pass.

Comment: It would seem that `oc login` is replaced by some [API authorization method](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python/blob/master/openshift/README.md#documentation-for-authorization) and `oc project` is replaced by providing an adequate `namespace` parameter to the endpoints in the [API](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python/blob/master/openshift/README.md).

Answer (score 2):

This mostly follows what is in the [dynamic client usage](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python) but I used the kubernetes.config.new_client_from_config() (to support multiple clients) where the config filename is the open shift config in /root/.kube/config (dangerous: keys to the kingdom, protect accordingly)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import kubernetes
>>> import openshift.dynamic
>>> import yaml

>>> k8s_client = kubernetes.config.new_client_from_config('config/k8s.10.150.114.10.config')
>>> dyn_client = openshift.dynamic.DynamicClient(k8s_client)
>>> v1_services = dyn_client.resources.get(api_version='extensions/v1beta1', kind='Deployment')

>>> service_data = yaml.load(open('squawker_stage.yaml'))

>>> print service_data
{'kind': 'Deployment', 'spec': {'template': {'spec': {'containers': 
[{'image': 'docker.com/lrmcfarland/squawker', 'name': 'squawker', 
'ports': [{'containerPort': 8000}]}]}, 'metadata': {'labels': {'app': 
'squawker'}}}, 'replicas': 3}, 'apiVersion': 'extensions/v1beta1', 
'metadata': {'namespace': 'squawker-staging', 'name': 'squawker'}}
```

At this point I needed to create the project, squawker-staging, in the GUI, but left it empty. I am still reading the fine manual for how to do that here and will update this when I do.

```
>>> resp = v1_services.create(body=service_data, namespace='squawker-staging')

>>> print(resp.metadata)
{u'creationTimestamp': u'2018-06-28T18:23:14Z',
 u'generation': 1,
 u'labels': {u'app': u'squawker'},
 u'name': u'squawker',
 u'namespace': u'squawker-staging',
 u'resourceVersion': u'1855021',
 u'selfLink': u'/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/squawker- 
 staging/deployments/squawker',
 u'uid': u'5268fa31-7b00-11e8-9e65-005056887570'}
```

Squawker is my simple flask server for container communication testing.